# What are the properties of data we have to have in order to do least square regression with just matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-regression

In the problem of linear regression, we are given $n$ observations $\{ (x_1, y_1),\dots,(x_n, y_n)\}$, where each input $x_i$ is a $d$-dimensional vector. Our goal is to estimate a linear predictor $f(.)$ which predicts $y$ given $x$ according to the formula
    \begin{equation}
    f(x) = x^\top\boldsymbol{\theta},
\end{equation}
    Let ${\bf y} = [y_1, y_2 \dots y_n]^\top$ be the $n \times 1$ vector of outputs and ${\bf X} = [x_1, x_2, \dots x_n]^\top$ be the $n \times d$ matrix of inputs. One possible way to estimate the parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is through minimization of the sum of squares. This is the least squares estimator:
    \begin{equation}
argmin_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \ \lVert {\bf y} - {\bf X}\boldsymbol{\theta} \rVert_2^2.
\label{eq:LS_q3}        
\end{equation}

So the optimal value of $\theta$ for this cost function is $\theta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. 
SO we need the matrix $X^TX$ to be invertible. What does this mean in terms of the data itself?

My thought was it has to do with covariance matrix somehow, but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $X^{\top}X$ is invertible iff $\operatorname{rank}(X^{\top}X)=\operatorname{rank}(X)=d$, i.e. $X$ does not contain a column that is a linear combination of other columns. Specifically, let $x_k$ denote the $k$-th column of $X$ and let $X_{-k}:=[x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1},x_{k+1},\ldots,x_d]$. Assume, for simplicity, that the sample average of each $x_k$ is $0$. Then the $(k,k)$-th entry of $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}$ is given by
\begin{align}
[(X^{\top}X)^{-1}]_{k,k}&=\left[x_k^{\top}(I_{d-1}-X_{-k}(X_{-k}^{\top}X_{-k})^{-1}X_{-k}^{\top})x_k\right]^{-1} \\
&=\left[x_k^{\top}x_k\left(1-\frac{x_k^{\top}X_{-k}(X_{-k}^{\top}X_{-k})^{-1}X_{-k}^{\top}x_k}{x_k{^\top}x_k}\right)\right]^{-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{(1-R_k^2)(x_k^{\top}x_k)},
\end{align}
where $R_k^2$ is the [$R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) in the regression of $x_k$ on the columns of $X_{-k}$. In particular, $R_k^2=1$ when $x_k=X_{-k}\beta$ for some $\beta\in \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$.

Comment: Thank you sir, I don't understand what does the regression of $x_k$ mean? Also, by taking inverses and doing reduction of the first line in the computation, I get $(x_k^T(I-I)x_k)^{-1}=0$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: Also how do you take inverses?

Comment: $(X_{-k}^TX_{-k})^{-1}=X_{-k}^{-1}(X_{-k}^{T})^{-1}$ and then they cancel out with the rest?

Comment: Typically it is assumed that $n>d$ so those matrices are not square.